# Есть ли способ проссумировать столбцы селекта и записать значение в нужный столбец?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image: Результат селекта]

Необходимо получить сумму нарастающим итогом, то есть в стобце % для первой записи необходимо указать значение из стобца %(27,5..), для второй записи 27,5... + 26,8.. = 54,3, для третьей записи 27,5.. + 26,8.. + 24,6.. = 78,9 и так далее.. Язык oracle sql, но можно для любого sql, если знаете решение, там уж адаптирую.

Comment: Если бы это была статическая структура, которая была бы заполнена 1 раз, я бы прописал скриптик, проставляющий нужные значения. Но увы данные постоянно обновляются, потому хотелось юы решить средствами селекта.

Comment: *Необходимо получить сумму нарастающим итогом* Кумулятивная сумма считается оконной функцией SUM(). https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions197.htm#SQLRF06115 PS. Не добавляйте факты как комментарии - корректируйте текст вопроса (ссылка "Править" под ним). PPS. *я бы прописал скриптик, проставляющий нужные значения.* Плохое знание SQL - не оправдание [censored] решений, а повод для самообучения.

Comment: Спасибо, @Akina